# How to call Python (cutting video into frames and then sending them as JSON) script from Jmeter?

Tags: python, jmeter

I am trying to load test an API, which receives images as JSON and sends them back with blurred faces. All of this is written in Python.
I call the following POST request:

```
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/function/flask-service", json=json.dumps(files)) #POST to server as json
```

Now I want to load test my API with JMETER.
The problem however is, that my Python script first needs to cut down a video into individual frames. This is why the JSON is different each time.

What do I have to do to pass JMETER different JSONS for the different frames my Python script extracts.

Answer (score 0):

You can call external programs and commands using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) for example somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) and store the individual frames as JSON files into a folder.

Then you can use [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md) plugin which reads next file from the specified directory into a [JMeter Variabl](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)e on each iteration of each virtual user.